# Javascript issue when adding a second script to the page

Tags: javascript, php, css

Both JS script works. My problem is that the First JS doesnt work the moment I add the second JS script. How can I fix this ?

First JS script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button1").click(function(){
        $("div1").toggleClass("grid");
    });
});
</script>
```

Second JS script

```
 <script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j("#trigger").change(function () {
        if ($j(this).data('options') == undefined) {
            $j(this).data('options', $j('select.switchable option').clone());
        }
        var id = $j(this).val();
        var that = this;
        $j("select.switchable").each(function () {
            var thisname = $j(this).attr('name');
            var theseoptions = $j(that).data('options').filter('.' + thisname + '_' + id);
            $j(this).html(theseoptions);
        });
    });
    //then fire it off once to display the correct elements
    $j('#trigger').trigger('change');
});

</script>
```

Comment: Take this `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` out of the second script and change all the `$j` references to just `$`.

Comment: are both scripts using jquery? If so, yes remove the noConflict and change the $j variable to $

Comment: Why don't you just do both action in one script ?

Comment: I tried adding both in one script and same result.

Comment: So you have a `<button1>` and `<div1>` elements?

Answer (score 0):

you should respect all document ready function the same way:
by removing **j** and using just **$**

First JS script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button1").click(function(){
        $("div1").toggleClass("grid");
    });
});
</script>
```

Second JS script

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#trigger").change(function () {
        if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
            $(this).data('options', $('select.switchable option').clone());
        }
        var id = $(this).val();
        var that = this;
        $("select.switchable").each(function () {
            var thisname = $(this).attr('name');
            var theseoptions = $(that).data('options').filter('.' + thisname + '_' + id);
            $(this).html(theseoptions);
        });
    });
    //then fire it off once to display the correct elements
    $('#trigger').trigger('change');
});

</script>
```